# Why can't I connect the clicked event of a QPushButton to a function inside a Python class?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to connect the clicked event of a QPushButton inside a class (MyButton) to a function inside the same class (print_hello_world) in PyQt5. I'm expecting to print "Hello World" when the user clicks on the button. Can anyone explain why the following code does not work? (i.e. clicking on the button does not print anything)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MyButton:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.push_button = QPushButton('Print', parent)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.print_hello_world)

    def print_hello_world(self):
        print("Hello World") 


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        button = MyButton(parent=self)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

The above code will work if I add `button.push_button.clicked.connect(lambda:button)` after I instantiate the MyButton object in the Window class. Can anyone explain to me why the first code does not work and the following code works?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MyButton:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.push_button = QPushButton('Print', parent)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.print_hello_world)

    def print_hello_world(self):
        print("Hello World") 


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        button = MyButton(parent=self)
        button.push_button.clicked.connect(lambda:button)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

What is an alternative way to make the first code work by modifying the `MyButton` class without having to add extra lines of code after instantiating the class?

Comment: To see why, add the following method to the `MyButton` class: `def __del__(self): print('deleted')`. In the second example, the `lambda` forms a closure over the `button` variable, which keeps it alive. If you want to add extra functionality to a widget, subclass it. (NB: the push-button itself is kept alive because it is linked to a parent on the Qt/C++ side).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm now subclassing `QWidget` and running `super().__init__()` in the `__init__` of the `MyButton`, and the connection that I make inside the class persists.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning and working on PyQt based software development. I did a few experiments with the code and by calling super initialization, the first code works fine. Here is the modified code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MyButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.push_button = QPushButton('Print', parent)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.print_hello_world)

    def print_hello_world(self):
        print("Hello World") 


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        button = MyButton(parent=self)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

'button' is destroyed because of garbage collection inside 'Window's init method, because it is not an instance variable so 'button' goes out of scope when init method finishes.

So this version works as intended:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MyButton:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.push_button = QPushButton('Print', parent)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.print_hello_world)

    def print_hello_world(self):
        print("Hello World") 


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.button = MyButton(parent=self)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```